# How to unit test a function with two return values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have a function inside a class which returns two dictionaries.

```
class A():
   def __init__(self):
       self.dict1={}
       self.dict2={}
   def funct1(self,a,b):
       self.dict1['a']=a
       self.dict2['b']=b
       return self.dict1,self.dict2
```

I want to write a unit test to test the function funct1 which return two dictionaries

Comment: And what's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: The two values are a single `tuple`.

Answer (score 2):

Python functions return exactly one object, *always*. In your case, that object is a tuple with two objects contained.

Just test those two objects; you could unpack them in an assignment and test the individual dictionaries, for example:

```
def test_func1_single(self):
    instance_under_test = A()
    d1, d2 = instance_under_test.func1(42, 81)
    self.assertEqual(d1, {'a': 42})
    self.assertEqual(d2, {'b': 81})

def test_func1_(self):
    instance_under_test = A()

    d1, d2 = instance_under_test.func1(42, 81)
    self.assertEqual(d1, {'a': 42})
    self.assertEqual(d2, {'b': 81})

    d3, d4 = instance_under_test.func1(123, 321)
    # these are still the same dictionary objects
    self.assertIs(d3, d1)
    self.assertIs(d4, d2)
    # but the values have changed
    self.assertEqual(d1, {'a': 123})
    self.assertEqual(d2, {'b': 321})
```

Exactly what you test is up to your specific use cases and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

A simple test would be

```
o = A()  # creates an instance of A
a, b = o.funct1(1, 2)  # call methods and unpack the result in two variables
assert a["a"] == 1 and b["b"] == 2  # test the values according to our precedent function call
```

Nothing counter intuitive in python